# choosing versioning software

Tags: system, document-versioning

I work on windows and I need a very simple version track software to be able to check in/out a folder project, no matter what's inside. I downloaded few programs, but most of them are very complicated, team work, cloud, thousands of options, etc.

I need some simple version track of my files, locally. Can you recommend me something useful?

Comment: What _did_ you try already? No sense in recommending anything you've already dismissed.[Update] Also this question is probably better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ [/Update]

Comment: I tried TortoiseSVN and CVS clints, GIT, RapidSVN. At work we use clearcase on linux which works great but it's not free and I use windows. I already use a batch for automatic archive with date, then email (backup) in a safe location. I'm looking by something more automatic.

Answer (score 1):

i'd recommend using simpy rar with datetime. Or as an option - just parameter to update archive instead of creating new one

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons why version control software have the number of options that they do, without understanding the basics of how the particular version control system that you are trying to use functions these options can seem overwhelming. To be able to use version control you will have to put in a little bit of effort to understand how it works. That being said I find that [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/) from Canonical makes a pretty good introduction to version control for beginners. It has a pretty nice [download](http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/Download) page for various platforms and comes with a GUI client and comes with [beginner friendly documentation](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.6/en/tutorials/index.html).

However, having used other version control systems I personally don't like to use Bazaar. The choice of version control system should not make a difference if you are only looking to use it yourself and don't need any of the more advanced features. If you are willing to invest some more time however, I would recommend trying Mercurial it has [some documentation for beginners](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BeginnersGuides) and a fairly nice beginner friendly GUI for Windows in the form of [EasyMercurial](http://easyhg.org/download.html).